# What constitutes an officially "failed" SE site?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, closed-proposals

In the latest post on the Stack Overflow blog titled "[Stack Overflow Around the World](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-overflow-around-the-world/)", Joel Spolsky mentions the following (emphasis mine):

> One thing we discovered early on about setting up new Stack Exchange communities is that they only work if you have a critical mass of experienced users who know how the system works. The Area 51 process is designed to insure that we only open sites for which we have a group of committed users. This process has worked well: so far we’ve opened 40+ sites of which **only two failed.**

But I'm not sure I understand what constitutes a failure based on the number mentioned:

- If you only consider officially "launched" sites, I don't believe there are any.
- If you consider sites that made it to beta, there are actually three:

  - [Gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets)
  - [Artificial Intelligence](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6607/artificial-intelligence)
  - [Atheism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2732/atheism)
- Of course, if you consider all the proposals that were closed, there are dozens (-ish?) of them.

The closest match seems to be the failed beta sites, so is it just a typo and it really should be three?

Or is there some other segment of SE sites (or even SE sites I'm not thinking of) that Stack Exchange, Inc. considers a failure?

Comment: No need to rub it in @studiohack

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Joel just misspoke (mistyped?).  There have been three site failures, which you listed.  I fixed the blog post.

Answer (score 4):

Joel remains sort of distant from SE daily operations, so he's probably not aware that it is now 3.

Comment: Or perhaps Joel doesn't even believe the Atheism SE site ever existed?

Comment: it's hard to believe in atheism

Comment: I'm skeptical about the whole process.

Comment: The question is, did it believe in Joel?