# Have any Stack Exchange Sites been shut down yet?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What constitutes an officially “failed” SE site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86477/what-constitutes-an-officially-failed-se-site)

Have any Stack Exchange Sites been shut down yet?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [the atheists](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2732/atheism) stopped believing in their site after going public.  Happened a month or so ago after a steady loss in interest.

Comment: At least they are consistent, they believe in nothing...

Comment: @Marcel: you're probably thinking of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihilism

Comment: **They lacked the Lord's guidance, I tells ya!**

Comment: @pcampbell: No, I didn't express myself clearly enough, I meant: they believe that nothing exists apart from ourselves.